# Are op-amps really superior to transistors for an audio tone control?

Tags: tone-control

I'm now working on a new hobby project, an audio amplifier using TDA2050 ICs in bridge configuration, to be fed by phone or PC earphone output. I already made the amplifier, it sounds fantastic. Two of these per channel.

When I started looking for tone control circuits, I find those using op-amps like 4558, 741, etc. and those using general purpose transistors.

Beyond any underlaying economical or simplicity reasons, is there a real overwhelming benefit on choosing op-amps over transistors for tone controls for HIFI home audio amplifiers?

As examples.

This:

[image]

VS. this:

[image]

Comment: Well, probably not much with that specific opamp.  The 741 isn't a very good opamp. 
 But with a modern opamp, temperature stability, power supply noise rejection and repeatability between circuits comes to mind as being better.

Comment: do you want to make a precise circuit or a creative one?

Comment: @user253751 I would like to try one not overkilling yet decent...more creative than precise

Comment: op-amps are good for precision and quick design; it is designed to work more-or-less perfectly; a simple transistor forces you to make tradeoffs you are dealing with raw nature instead of something designed by a human to be almost perfect

Comment: @user253751 ....transistor ...you are dealing with raw nature <= LOL!

Comment: The 741 was an _absolutely terrific op-amp when it came out_.  In 1975 or something.  In the past 50 years, though, manufacturers _have_ learned how to do better.  Much, much better.  I think it only has life because people keep recycling ancient circuits.  By rights, the 741 should only have a life in obsolete industrial, medical, and military electronics that are clinging to life because the paperwork to upgrade them is worse than sourcing antique components.  _You_ don't have that constraint.  _You_ can use new parts.

Comment: To subtract a bit from the ritual and deserved slagging of the ancient 741, there are also worse op-amps for audio that are newer and far more popular. Eg. LM358 with massive crossover distortion.

Comment: It's not funny, it's serious. You're dealing with how electrons and holes behave in a certain semiconductor in the presence of a slightly different semiconductor - not much effort has been put in to make it "nice". An op-amp is designed quite hard to be "nice".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what about 4558? I also see a lot diagrams using these

Comment: @AramAlvarez The makers describe each half of the 4558 as "similar" to the 741 (they were going for replacement). It's actually got significantly better performance (noise, GBW etc.) where it matters for audio (and no worse for DC) but not so much better that it will likely misbehave in a well-designed circuit when substituted. If  you stick a modern  85MHz op-amp into a design that mostly works with a 741, bad things might happen. The 4558 is pretty old too, ~40 years I think.

Comment: I lovehate how much these schematics are *obviously* been copied over and over and over again, then "improved" with meaningless color and the last thief of that intellectual property then had the audacity to slap their URL right across the middle of the schematic. Aram, hint: whenever you see a schematic that has more JPEG compression artifact than a 1996 cat picture, you know it's been copied by at least one person in the chain of stealing that had not the slightest clue. You can thus be almost certain that websites that propagate these kinds of circuits are low quality.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes I know what you are talking about. These diagrams I put them as just examples of OPAmps vs transistors, not as a precise comparation

Comment: small nit-pick, but aren't op-amps composed mostly of transistors (and resistors)?  Thus the question would seem to be which is better, a single transistor, or a network of transistors (and resistors) presumably designed and optimized for a purpose such as this?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, likely you can buy better op-amps for Hi-Fi than you can make yourself from multiple transistors. And likely op-amps are better than just a single transistor amplifier, but it might suffice if you don't require much performance.

Also, op-amps like 741 or 4558 are made of transistors, so in the end they are also just a bunch of transistors, better than a single transistor. Before op-amp ICs were available, op-amps were modules made of discrete transistors and other components. Before transistors were available, op-amps were even larger modules made with thermionic valves (electron tubes).

Although if you want Hi-Fi like you say, you might want to use other components in place of TDA2050 or ua741, better components exist.

Comment: The 741 opamp came out in 1968 as a general purpose amplifier, not for audio. It is noisy and has trouble above 9kHz. Use a modern opamp made for audio like an OPA134 or TL071.

Comment: Gotta love the sound you get from a tube amp <3

Answer (score 9):

Now that all of the (1968) 741 thumping is out of the way,,,,,

An opamp is superior because of how it interacts with the frequency-modifying networks.  Compared to *any* single bipolar transistor circuit configuration, an opamp will have a nearly perfect zero-ohm output impedance (critical for driving feedback networks), and either a nearly-infinite impedance non-inverting input or a nearly perfect virtual-ground inverting input.

All of that means that the tone control networks will behave exactly as the math predicts.  The driving-point impedance seen by the lower schematic R2 and C4 is a significant fraction of the impedances of those components, and  will change as a function of signal amplitude.  This will cause non-ideal frequency-shaping effects, and interaction between the two control settings.

Similarly, the upper schematic R3-C3 node is tied to a virtual GND, so there is no interaction between the bass and treble settings.  The Q1 input impedance is not nearly low enough to prevent this.

Comment: correct. It is interesting that in professional analogue consoles, FET opamps are typically preferred in EQ circuits, whereas bipolar designs (often the venerable 5532) are used in drivers, pre-amps and so on, most likely because their very high input impedance loads the CR networks used in the filter circuits much less, and allows smaller C's to be used.

Answer (score 5):

A modern audio opamp is made for and used for hifi. It has many transistors for extremely high gain and bandwidth that creates very low distortion and full audio bandwidth.
Here is the awful distortion of a single transistor similar to the old tone controls circuit you found:

[image: distortion]

Comment: Of course, an electrical engineer's awful distortion may be a sound engineer's awesome overdrive... most popular when produced by the valves in guitar amps, but also studio equipment often prefers discrete transistors, in part because they distort early and smoothly when the input gets to the limit. By contrast, op-amps first distort almost not at all and then suddenly hard-clip, which sounds much worse. (Which, of course, can also sometimes be just what the musician wants...)

Comment: @leftaroundabout exactly - that's why my first question was "do you want a precise circuit or a creative one?" :)

Comment: 1. Single transistor tone control circuits should not operate with the voltage swing you show. 2. The transistor’s operating point can be set to the peak of the hFE-lC curve so for “small “ signals the linearity is not as bad as the simulation suggests. 3. The lower diagram in the OP shows negative feedback which also improves small signal linearity.

Comment: @leftaroundabout BJT transistors have wide enough variation that it does not make sense to use them without considerable negative feedback, and then they clip pretty hard.  The solid-state simulation of tube amp overdrive is usually done with JFETs instead.

Comment: The fairly high level I showed occurs frequently in hifi peak levels (+20dB above average levels). 30% distortion sounds awful. Radio stations use lots of compression which also sounds "wrong".

Comment: actually this kind of soft, asymmetrical distortion is considered fairly pleasing, by many. But of course it is undesirable in a chain where fidelity is the goal.

Answer (score 5):

Either is, of course, the standard Baxandall tone control circuit that essentially zeroes a frequency-dependent adjustable bridge between signal and negative feedback from an inverting amplifier.

The single-transistor version has no dependable amplification factor, limited linearity, variable noise performance, considerable quiescent current that drives noise via heating components.

The opamp version, in contrast, has quite constant design parameters.  It will inherently have crossover distortion but will go to considerable lengths to obviate its effects, and in connection with bypass capacitors there are well-documented ways to get rid of it.

Noise performance will be good, quiescent current for low-noise low-distortion operation will usually be considerably less than the single-transistor version.

You wouldn't use transistors from the 70s, and of course you wouldn't use the 741.  You can pick opamps that fit your use regarding the specs.  Inverting configuration means that you need not worry about common-mode distortion, so you can pick a JFET opamp like the OPA2134 that has no specific common-mode distortion compensation (like OPA1642 has) that will have very high input impedance (and thus not sap the Baxandall network operation), no relevant input current noise given the variable Baxandall network impedances, and input voltage noise of 8nV/√Hz which corresponds more or less to the noise of a 3.2kΩ resistor which is small in relation to the other impedances (one might lower all impedances for less overall noise).

You can also pick other opamps with different noise figures, input impedances, slew rates and so on and match the circuit to it (with regard to a tone network, it would be customary to add a small capacitor as direct negative feedback for high frequencies that cuts off amplification outside of the audible range).

In short, using opamps allows you to design your circuit in terms of directly audio-relevant parameters and design constraints with high precision and dependable results.

And on-chip compensation networks and laser-trimmed components allow for a precision and functional simplicity that you just don't get with isolated components.

Comment: " You wouldn't use transistors from the 70s "  I would.  The "A" in Motorola's MPA series of discrete transistors stands for Audio.

Comment: @AnalogKid They don't produce transistors with the same processes now as they did in the 70s.  For example, the original RCA 2N3055 had way lower bandwidth than what is sold nowadays under that part number but was quite harder to kill via secondary breakdown: the modern epitaxial processes create a different problem space.

Comment: I still have a little amplifier I built from 2N2222 transistors around 1977. Not a great amplifier by any means--but it would still take little short of an actual miracle to get a 741 to reproduce audio nearly as accurately.

Answer (score 1):

"Are op-amps really superior to transistors for an audio tone control?"

Well, the answer depends on how you define the "superiority". As tone controls are there to modify the signal, or to put it differently to wilfully "distort" the signal, it depends on if you like the resulting effect better or not.

In hifi circuits (the people, not the electronics) intentional distortion is sometimes used to say that, as example, a tube amplifier makes the sound warmer. In studio recording "intentional distortion" is used a lot, all from tone controls and various compressors and echos and so on, in order to "heighten the experience".

It all comes back to what you want to achieve by "distorting the signal". If the purpose is to "heighten your experience" use whatever sounds best to your ears (never mind other peoples ears). If the purpose is to "somewhat mitigate errors in other parts of the sound chain" you are probably better off using op-amps than using a few transistors, or even better might by using a signal processor using FFT or other algorithms to modify the sound (so called room correction as available in some speaker systems).